# how to sort part-duplicates in a set near each other in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, set

i have a set of strings like this:
`('item:214', 'product:10', 'file:123', 'table:v', 'item:21', 'item:124', 'table:s')`

i want to sort it from more frequent to less frequent and then the rest:
`('item:214', 'item:21', 'item:124', 'table:v', 'table:s', 'product:10', 'file:123')`

i have to first slice each item from the start through ':' and then find other items with the same sliced string in them then add the matches to a list:

```
def sort_pv(p_set, pv_set):
    sorted_list = []
    for p in p_set:
        for pv in pv_set:
            if p.lower() == pv[:pv.index(':')].lower():
                sorted_list.append(pv)
    return sorted_list
```

this is what i come up with so far but it has 2 major flaws:

first the part-duplicate items round up with each other but items without a match gets put in between duplicate matches like so:
`['item:214', 'item:21', 'item:124', 'product:10', 'file:123', 'table:v', 'table:s']`

second the '''sorted_list''' has duplicates in it, i tried to fix that by using `set()` but that mixes up the order

Answer (score 1):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

strings = (
    "item:214",
    "product:10",
    "file:123",
    "table:v",
    "item:21",
    "item:124",
    "table:s",
)

c = Counter(s.split(":")[0] for s in strings)

strings = sorted(strings, key=lambda k: c[k.split(":")[0]], reverse=True)
print(strings)
```

Prints:

```
['item:214', 'item:21', 'item:124', 'table:v', 'table:s', 'product:10', 'file:123']
```

To remove duplicates:

```
out, seen = [], set()
for s in strings:
    if not s in seen:
        out.append(s)
        seen.add(s)

print(out)
```